# What is the implementation of call() in dart?

Tags: dart, callable

I somehow found the `call()` method is on every function. 
Using this method I could change my `if (callback != null) callback()` to `callback?.call()`.

So I tried to find the implementation and document of `call()`, but I couldn't. Is it just built-in method? What will be the implementation of this method? `Function.apply()` will be called inside it?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

All Dart *functions* (objects which has a function type rather than an class/interface type) have a `call` method.

The `call` method has the same function type as the function itself, and it behaves exactly the same when you call it. You could even say that calling a function *is* implicitly calling its `call` method. 
And, not by coincidence, the specification actually does say that: If you write the function invocation `e1(e2, e3)`, then the compiler checks if `e1` has `call` method, and if so converts it to the *method* invocation `e1.call(e2, e3)`.

Other Dart objects may have a `call` method too. It's just a normal method for interface types, but if class `C` has a call method like `int call(int x) => ...`, and `c` has type `C`, then `c(e2, e3)` is also converted to `c.call(e2, e3)`. It has to be a `call` *method*, not just a `call` getter returning a function.

Comment: For future reference, the Dart Language Specification, version 2.10 gives the details in 17.15.5.   I was looking too.

Comment: Calling a function through "call" is slow. Wonders.

Comment: That probably depends on what else your are doing. A quick benchmark I wrote up shows no significant difference between doing `f(i)` and `f.call(i)` when `f` has a function type. https://dartpad.dev/c42130fcee303bc7a342ebeef36429a6?null_safety=true

Comment: I think it even depends on what you are doing.  Dart is a better Java, intentionally built for speed.  It doesn't have reflection or anything dynamic like Java or Javascript.  It compiles down to the same exact thing.

Comment: As far as I understand, the aforementioned spec section 17.15.5 explains how `e()` may get translated to `e.call()`, which is unrelated. The fact that every `Function` has a `.call` method is actually specified in 20.5 "Function Types".