# Walk through nested dictionary in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

in dart I have a nested list of elements

```
void main() {
  
  var diction = <String, dynamic>{'1':'Alpha','2':'Beta','3':{'x':'Football','y':'Golf'},'4':{'a':'Samba','b':'Tango','c':'FoxTrott','d':'Waltz'}};
}
```

and a list of keys that walk you through the dict, e.g.

```
var keyList = ['4','a']
```

The problem is, that I cannot just use

```
diction['4','a']
```

but have to use

```
diction['4']['a']
```

How can I use to call a dictionary like in the last case?

Answer (score 2):

`operator []` takes only a single argument.  That is the syntax of the language, and you cannot change that.

Possible actions:

- Do nothing.  Just use `dict[key1][key2]` and live with it.  It's not clear to me that something like `dict[key1, key2]` would be any real improvement.
- Directly construct a [`LinkedHashMap`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-collection/LinkedHashMap/LinkedHashMap.html) that uses a `List` as its key.  You would need to supply `equals` and `hashCode` callbacks since `List` equality normally is based on object identity and does not perform a deep equality check. (Similarly, normally each `List` instance would have a distinct `hashCode`.) When that's all done, you could use `dict[[key1, key2]]`.  Note that with this approach, you conceivably could have a variable number of keys.
- Use [`package:tuple`](https://pub.dev/packages/tuple) and use a `Tuple2` for the key.  Then you could use `dict[Tuple2(key1, key2)]`.  Since tuples are "value" types and implement `operator ==` and `hashCode`, you could use `Tuple2` directly without needing to do extra work.
- Derive your own `Map`-based class.  You probably would want to derive from [`package:collection`'s `DelegatingMap`](https://pub.dev/documentation/collection/latest/collection/DelegatingMap-class.html) class, which would provide most of the implementation for you.  From there you could add your own methods that take multiple keys and that internally perform nested lookups.  If you add a [`call(Key1 key1, Key2 key2)` method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58833763/179715), instances of your custom `Map` would become function-like objects, and you then callers could use `dict(key1, key2)` to perform lookups.  Note that you would not be able to set items in your custom `Map` using the same syntax.  Or instead of using `call()`, you could add `get(Key1 key1, Key2 key2)` and `set(Key1 key1, Key2 key2, Value value)` methods.

Answer (score -1):

You can create an object that does what you what, just extend LinkedHashMap:

```
class MyHashMap extends LinkedHashMap
```

Then you have to implement the 21 methods of the abstract class and you are good to go!