# How to show button depending on a optional void function in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a class where I declare an `optional void function` as `parameter` for the constructor of that class.
If the parameter (that optional void function) is not null I want to show a button.
On my second class I call the constructor and I pass a function to that optional parameter.
The problem is that my button never shows up on the screen and I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Can someone please help me to figure out where is the issue in my code ?

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function(void)?
      showCreateAccountBtn; // This parameter is optional and represent a void function.
  const Login({
    Key? key,
    this.showCreateAccountBtn,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Login> createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("First Screen")
        ),
        body: Column(children: [
          widget.showCreateAccountBtn != null
              ? TextButton(
                  style: ButtonStyle(
                      foregroundColor:
                          MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.blue)),
                  onPressed: () => widget.showCreateAccountBtn,
                  child: const Text('Create an account'))
              : const SizedBox()
        ]));
  }
}

class FirstScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FirstScreen> createState() => _FirstScreenState();
}

class _FirstScreenState extends State<FirstScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Login(showCreateAccountBtn: _onCreateAccountTapped());
  }

  Function(void)? _onCreateAccountTapped() {
    print("Click on Create Acc");

    return null;
  }
}
```

Here is the GIST link (not working for unknown reasons): https://dartpad.dev/?id=58294fa8eed37b016d0b257fee2f1317

Thanks for reading this !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onPressed: () => widget.showCreateAccountBtn,`
to this
`onPressed: widget.showCreateAccountBtn?.call(),`

more info here [What is the implementation of call() in dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58833369/what-is-the-implementation-of-call-in-dart)

Comment: I tried your advice but I'm getting an error saying that is looking for a parameter in my `call` function.  If I pass an empty void call the button still don't show up:
`onPressed: () => widget.showCreateAccountBtn?.call(() {}())`
If I remove the `void` parameter from the function is also not showing the button. I really don't know what can be the issue.

Comment: @FlorentinLupascu use `VoidCallback? showCreateAccountBtn ` instead of `Function(void)?
      showCreateAccountBtn`

Comment: I have updated the GIST project but unfortunately the solution from you is not working on my small example (the button is not showing). Do you have any idea what else can cause the issue ?

Comment: which button? here is only one button in your code and it's always showing

Comment: Is ok because your answer was the right one. The problem was the return in the function `_onCreateAccountTapped ` where I was returning null.

Answer (score 0):

```
onPressed: () => widget.showCreateAccountBtn,
```

to this :

```
onPressed: () => widget.showCreateAccountBtn!(),
```

Comment: Thanks Mohamed for your fast reply! I've tried your solution but the button still don't show up.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the full fix:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const FirstScreen());

class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  final VoidCallback? showCreateAccountBtn; 
  const Login({
    Key? key,
    this.showCreateAccountBtn,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Login> createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text("First Screen")),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(children: [
            widget.showCreateAccountBtn != null ? 
            TextButton(
                    style: ButtonStyle(
                        foregroundColor:
                            MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(Colors.red)),
                    onPressed: () => widget.showCreateAccountBtn?.call(),
                    child: const Text('Create an account'))
                : const SizedBox()
          ]),
        ));
  }
}

class FirstScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FirstScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FirstScreen> createState() => _FirstScreenState();
}

class _FirstScreenState extends State<FirstScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        ),
        title: "My App",
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Login(showCreateAccountBtn: () => _onCreateAccountTapped()));
  }

  void _onCreateAccountTapped() {
    return () {
      print("Click on Create Acc");
    } ();
  }
}
```